# Exporting multiple pages to PDF in a specific order

Tags: vba, excel, pdf-generation, excel-2010

I am trying to export pages from two different sheets of a workbook as 1 PDF.

However, I want the pages to be in this order: 1 page from Sheet1, 5 pages from Sheet2, 2 pages from Sheet1.

At the moment I am exporting these as 3 seperate PDFs and then merging them afterwards in another application.

The code I have been using is below:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sPath & quotept1filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=1, OpenAfterPublish:=False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sPath & quotept2filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=2, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("PPA Print Ready Quote").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=sPath & optionsfilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=NumberOfOptions, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

How can I get them to print as one PDF in the order I want?

Comment: You can set up a tab in your file that has each section in the order you want it to print with page breaks, formatting, and such, but the data is linked to the original sheets. Then you just print that sheet. If the formatting between the sections is too different to fit in one tab, you could use multiples tabs to set it up in the order you want, then select all the tabs before printing it, and it will print in your desired order. You can also keep this sheet(s) hidden so no one else sees them.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really want to add more tabs to the workbook. I use this method about 6 times and it would mean adding about another 20 tabs. I also don't want to duplicate data. Could I select the ranges I want as an array and then export that?

Comment: You could try selecting each region simultaneously and print the selection only, but it won't work across multiple sheets. I think you are stuck with your current method, or the one I proposed. Duplicating data isn't all that uncommon in excel, especially for formatting / presentation purposes. I have done it and seen it done MANY times. You could just have the macro duplicate the data in the order you want, then print it to PDF, then wipe it out.

Comment: I think I'll stick with my current method. I don't want to duplicate because it can lead to too many errors. I don't want to check/update duplicate pages for all of the tabs that I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not trying to convince you, just shedding some more light (hopefully) It's not duplicating, really. You would just link the 2nd page to the values you already have, using formulas. Nothing to check once you set it up the first time.

Comment: I found this while I was trying to control the order the sheets exported in.  My solution to that problem was to [reorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.move) the sheets before I exported them and then put them back afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It may not seem like the best way, but I personally use a driver such a PrimoPDF to do this.  By printing all the pages required to PrimoPDF you will gain one pdf file in the same order that it would appear if you were sending to a standard printer.

It can be downloaded for free here http://www.primopdf.com/

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really help me. I can't install such a driver on every client's pc. I need to do it through code.