# Excell VBA export some worksheets to PDF with ExportAsFixedFormat in a specified order

Tags: vba, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a PDF report in Excel which consists of a TitleSheet and a ReportSheet.  When I select the two sheets I need and use ExportAsFixedFormat to generate the PDF I can't seem to control the order which the sheets are added to the document.  As of now, the TitleSheet ends up at the bottom of the ReportSheet... not very helpful.

Here's my relevant code and some comments for things I tried that didn't work.

```
    Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ReportSheet.Name & ".PDF", "PDF(*.pdf),*.pdf*", 1, "Save As PDF File")
If FilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub


TitleSheet.Select 'so it's the first in the DPF report, no worky
Dim PrintSheets(1) As Variant

PrintSheets(0) = TitleSheet.Name 'changed index order, no worky
PrintSheets(1) = ReportSheet.Name
Sheets(PrintSheets).Select 'select both sheets so they both print

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    FilePath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
ReportSheet.Activate 'select this sheet so it's visible at the end
```

I looked for a few other answers ([Exporting multiple pages to PDF in a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804102/exporting-multiple-pages-to-pdf-in-a-specific-order)) but no cigar yet.  I have different column widths between the TitlePage and the ReportPage so I don't want to go through the headache of merging those.  I also can't use a 3rd party PDF creator because a mojority of users don't have admin rights on their machines to install any additional software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching and testing I found out that ExportAsFixedFormat exports sheets based on the tab/index order.  Which means I need to index ReportSheet after TitleSheet with this line of code:

```
ReportSheet.Move after:=TitleSheet
```

Viola!  Special thanks to Ken Puls: (http://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?234-Reorder-pages-when-exporting-as-PDF&highlight=ExportAsFixedFormat)